# PHP documentation links need a cleanup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link

Back in the earliest days of PHP, people ran various localized mirrors of the PHP website, including documentation. The main site has always lived at https://www.php.net but mirrors lived under subdomains like `ca2.php.net`. Those subdomains don't work anymore, but [there's lots of links like that still hanging around Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ca2.php.net). Some of them probably need to be updated to HTTPS as well

Per [Shog9 on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/244695), I am requesting a staff cleanup of these links. They only need to be pointed to the `www` version of the PHP site. The full list of subdomains is as follows (many thanks to [Derick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508057/derick) for getting me a list)

| hostname |
| --- |
| am1.php.net |
| ar2.php.net |
| at1.php.net |
| at2.php.net |
| au1.php.net |
| au2.php.net |
| ba1.php.net |
| bd1.php.net |
| be2.php.net |
| bg2.php.net |
| br1.php.net |
| br2.php.net |
| ca1.php.net |
| ca2.php.net |
| ca3.php.net |
| ch1.php.net |
| cl1.php.net |
| cn2.php.net |
| cz1.php.net |
| cz2.php.net |
| de1.php.net |
| de2.php.net |
| dk1.php.net |
| dk2.php.net |
| ee1.php.net |
| es1.php.net |
| fi1.php.net |
| fi2.php.net |
| fr2.php.net |
| hk1.php.net |
| hk2.php.net |
| id1.php.net |
| ie1.php.net |
| ie2.php.net |
| il1.php.net |
| in1.php.net |
| in2.php.net |
| in3.php.net |
| ir1.php.net |
| ir2.php.net |
| is1.php.net |
| is2.php.net |
| it1.php.net |
| it2.php.net |
| jm2.php.net |
| jp1.php.net |
| jp2.php.net |
| kr1.php.net |
| li1.php.net |
| lt1.php.net |
| lu1.php.net |
| lv1.php.net |
| md1.php.net |
| mx1.php.net |
| mx2.php.net |
| my1.php.net |
| nc1.php.net |
| nl1.php.net |
| nl3.php.net |
| no1.php.net |
| no2.php.net |
| nz2.php.net |
| pa1.php.net |
| pl1.php.net |
| ro1.php.net |
| ru2.php.net |
| se1.php.net |
| se2.php.net |
| sg2.php.net |
| si1.php.net |
| si2.php.net |
| th1.php.net |
| tr1.php.net |
| tr2.php.net |
| tw1.php.net |
| tw2.php.net |
| tz1.php.net |
| ua1.php.net |
| ua2.php.net |
| uk1.php.net |
| uk3.php.net |
| us1.php.net |
| us2.php.net |
| us3.php.net |
| vn1.php.net |
| za1.php.net |

Comment: Oops, I missed the part where it said, "staff," and cleaned up a couple. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's unfortunate you can't do a search like [url:am1.php.net or url:am2.php.net](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aam1.php.net+or+url%3Aam2.php.net) and see how *bad* the problem *might* be.

Comment: Outside of URLs (e.g. in code comments) they're likely a problem as well. While I could imagine edge-cases where a simple find & replace would cause harm these are extremely unlikely to actually occur. I've got an old edit bot hanging around and could run it to do that, if a mod wants me to. Disadvantage is of course the edit spam which a staff rewrite could avoid, I've used it previously to replace the access-vba tag at a relatively low pace to keep the front page from filling up with these edits

Comment: @ErikA Yeah, Glorfindel runs one as well, and he suggested the staff edit route instead. Looking to avoid mass edits

Comment: Note that the non-numbered country-code subdomains were also commonly used. E.g. the mirrors at `us1.php.net`, `us2.php.net`, `us3.php.net` would be available at `us.php.net` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for everyones patience on this one. We have completed the swap of all of the requested URLs.